# Java - Streaming JMS messages into an Oracle table

Tags: java, jdbc, spring-boot, stream, jms

We are using Spring Boot and JDBC to capture JMS messages and persist them to a DB table.

To make as little memory footprint as possible, we would like to stream these messages into the DB and batch commit them.

Is it possible to stream these messages into the database?

Currently, we have multiple JMS listeners consuming from our JMS queue. These listeners share an LinkedBlockingQueue (it's wrapped by a service) which they write the message to. This queue is then consumed from until it's depleted with the results being stored in a List. These results are persisted using Spring's JdbcTemplate.

We'd like to lower the memory footprint as these messages are being stored in the intermediate list solely to allow a batch save.

Any advice or proven pattern to follow in this case?

Comment: What is considered the transaction boundary?  If the consumption of a message is a transaction then it seems the result should be persisted as part of that transaction.  How would results sitting in the queue be recovered if the JVM, network, etc goes down?

Comment: Good point regarding the transaction boundary. I'm thinking a better option might be to consume a list of messages, say, 2000 at a time and simply persist them without adding any fancy batching mechanism. The transaction boundary is at the listener level. This way we'd still maintain consistency with what has/hasn't been consumed. I see that just pushing them to a queue will lose transaction information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to chunk streams using the handy StreamEx library.
However, we are still running into JVM memory issues upon stream materialisation. We'll need to run some further performance and garbage collection tests.

The code to stream is as follows:

```
try (StreamEx<MyEntity> stream = StreamEx.of(myEntities)) {
            stream.groupRuns((prev, next) -> recordCounter.incrementAndGet() % myApplicationProperties.getBatchSize() != 0)
                    .forEach((chunk) -> {
                        if (chunk.size() != 1) {
                            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(chunk);
                        } else {
                            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(chunk.get(0));
                        }
                    });
        }
```